# Set iframe height when contentWindow / contentDocument not available

Tags: javascript, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an `<iframe>` showing a facebook post, unfortunately I cannot find how to set the `<iframe>` height, so have to do this manually (for each post). Is there a way to ensure an iframes height matches the inner content when contentDocument is not accessible?

Comment: By manualy you mean waiting for the iframe load event, and then accesing the contentDocument height?
contentDocument is not available until the iframe have loaded.

Comment: Since the iframe is coming from another domain then I get Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://<my_domain>" from accessing a cross-origin frame....

Comment: So you put the iframe code into your page directly? In that case, there is no way to do that. If you use the JS SDK instead to embed the post, that will handle this automatically.

Comment: The JS SDK suggests a div as follows (from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts?locale=en_GB#add-code-manually ) `<div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/20531316728/posts/10154009990506729/" data-width="500"></div>` be added to the page.  When I do this, but the SDK never looks at the added element, since my site is an SPA then there is no page load event & I'm guessing FB relies on onload event, but there is none, so the above sits there like a lemon.